# Set background color of toolbar to white, without gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor_1', {
    toolbar: [
        { ..... },
    ],
    uiColor: 'white',
});
```

does not produce the desired result.

```
.cke_top{background-color: white;}
```

in css seems to have no effect.

```
.cke_top{display:none;}
```

hides the whole toolbar, but I have some buttons to display.

Some others have asked similar questions, but I cannot find the answers I need there.

Thanks in advance for comments.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, anyway try `.cke_top{background-color: white !important ;}`

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is a background image

```
span#cke_1_top {
    background-image: none;
}
```